# Using a Famo.us RenderController to stack container

Tags: stack, lifecycle, famo.us

From what I understand from Famo.us, the life cycle of a Renderable is managed by the framework  and as a result is we can remove node from the render tree.

I found that RenderController is responsible from showing or hiding elements. 
The problem with RenderController or even with the Lightbox is that I can't stack views. As soon as I call
 `myRenderController.show(surfaceA);
myRenderController.show(surfaceB);`

The surfaceA fade off and isn't visible anymore.

How can I create a kind of stacked layout where I can manage visility of each layer ?

Comment: you can use multiple render controllers. I use 4 in the present app I'm working on. One for the header, one for the menu, one for the content, and one for a modal that sits a top everything.

Comment: I upvoted what @aintnorest says, because he is correct.  I answered with an example to show exactly what is meant in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RenderController` applies the control to one node in the render tree.  Add a render controller for each node you wish to control.

**[Working Example Here](http://jsbin.com/xobeje/1/edit?js,output)**

The code link above shows a simple example of how the `RenderController` can be used to swap surfaces as well as hiding them from view.

#### Two RenderControllers:

```js
  var rendererOne = new RenderController();
  var rendererTwo = new RenderController();

  mainContext.add(modTop).add(rendererOne);
  mainContext.add(modBottom).add(rendererTwo);

  // Show both surfaces first
  rendererOne.show(surfaceOne);
  rendererTwo.show(surfaceTwo);

  // Swaps who has visibility on a double click
  var showing = true;
  Engine.on('dblclick', function(e){
    if (showing) {
      rendererTwo.hide();
      rendererOne.show(surfaceOne);
    } else {
      rendererOne.hide();
      rendererTwo.show(surfaceTwo);
    }
    showing = !showing;
  });
```